# How to be smart about User Interface component positioning in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I know I could create a base form and then inherit from and extend upon that, but that's not really what I'm referring to.

I want to do simple things like copy a label or textbox from one tab and paste it in exactly the same co-ordinates on another tab. Does Visual Studio 2010 have any tools that make this easier (so I don't have to manually check the Top and Left properties of every component). In general, are there some tools that make these kind of tasks easier (eg. Paste at same Left, same Top, same Right, same Bottom, same Width, same Height)?

Are there any good ideas in this area out there? **Something like a GUI standards-enforcer plugin or tool that can work with or within Visual Studio 2010.**

Comment: What on earth is the Close vote for? "not programming related"? "too vague"? What?

Comment: If you have a number of common controls that go on each form maybe design a form with only these controls first and then create as many copies of the form as you need, then add custom controls to each form as you wish? Just a suggestion?

Comment: Can't tell from here, but what about creating a user control, with all the "common" controls on it?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, not familiar with User Controls unfortunately. I'm really more asking about IDE functionality or something like a GUI standards enforcer plugin or tool.

Comment: If you create a usercontrol (Add user control in a project). Then you bang all the child controls on it, and sort out their positions. Build, it will appear in the components tool box. Then you position that control, the child controls are positioned within the user control, job done. If there are some groups of controls that are pretty static...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have any built-in tools/methods to make this easier (as far as I know). Perhaps the *smart* thing is to not waste too much time looking for shortcuts and just check the coordinates. It'll probably ward off dementia better than the using the desired IDE plugin/tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you multi-select controls and copy and past, their positions are kept relative to one another, so you would only have to remember the position of one control, and the rest would follow.

Another way around it would be to put a dummy control at 0,0 and always multi select using that dummy control and the controls you want.  That way you have an anchor that you know goes at 0,0.

Answer (score 1):

Cloning controls is very troublesome, they have far too many properties.  But this question sounds like it is talking about a TabControl and a need to have a particular control visible on every tab.  Which is trivial to implement, just change the control's Parent property:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        button1.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    }
```

With the assumption that button1 is a button that was originally placed on the 1st tabpage.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the idea Hans, but I'm really talking about Visual Studio IDE functionality or plugins that can help with GUI layout across a whole solution (apart from using base forms within the code).